Nginx could not find FastCGI UNIX domain socket
I have a FastCGI application listening on a UNIX socket at /tmp/web.socket.
srw-rw----. 1 nginx nginx 0 Aug 14 15:48 /tmp/web.socket

As the nginx user, I am able to access this socket:
[nginx@he4]:~$ ncat -U /tmp/web.socket
test^D
[nginx@he4]:~$ 

The ^D represents me manually adding a EOF.
Of course, "test" is not valid FastCGI:
- - [Wed, 14 Aug 2024 08:05:05 GMT] WARN read: connection closed
- - [Wed, 14 Aug 2024 08:05:05 GMT] WARN FastCGI: connection closed while reading frame size
- - [Wed, 14 Aug 2024 08:05:05 GMT] WARN FastCGI: connection severed at start
- - [Wed, 14 Aug 2024 08:05:05 GMT] WARN FastCGI: bad code

But at least this means that my FastCGI application is receiving the data from ncat.
My nginx runs under the nginx user and the nginx group. It uses a configuration slightly modified from the default Fedora configuration:
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name _;
        root /tmp;
        location / {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/web.socket;
        }
    }
}

It, however, cannot seem to find the socket:
2024/08/14 15:54:30 [crit] 464651#464651: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/web.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/web.socket:", host: "localhost"

I would appreciate any help.
(I am aware of the lack of TLS, and it does not seem relevant for the purposes of this question.)

The systemd unit file for nginx.service on Fedora is the following:
[Unit]
Description=The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
# Nginx will fail to start if /run/nginx.pid already exists but has the wrong
# SELinux context. This might happen when running `nginx -t` from the cmdline.
# https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1268621
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

PrivateTmp=true uses namespaces to give nginx a private /tmp. Moving the socket file outside of /tmp works.

I have to tell nginx where to find the FastCGI (socket) binary:
location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

This works for me, if i omit the fastcgi_pass setting (or it point to the wrong socket file) nginx cannot start FastCGI.

I specified it correctly already; see fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/web.socket; which was written in my question. Anyways, the issue turns out to be systemd creating namespaces.
